# Formatting text in input angular

Tags: html, angular, typescript, formatting

How can I make my code that when I click the bold button my input starts to write in bold and when I click it again I can write in normal again? Something like this: This **is the** result

[image]

Buttons :

```
<mat-button-toggle-group #toggleGroup2="matButtonToggleGroup" multiple style="display: flex; align-items: left;" (change)="onValChange(group.value)">
     <mat-button-toggle type="button" value="bold"><mat-icon>format_bold</mat-icon></mat-button-toggle>
     <mat-button-toggle type="button" value="italic"> <mat-icon>format_italic</mat-icon></mat-button-toggle>
     <mat-button-toggle type="button" value="underline"><mat-icon>format_underlined</mat-icon></mat-button-toggle>
 </mat-button-toggle-group>
```

Textarea:

```
<textarea id="description" matInput placeholder="Description..." formControlName="description" matTextareaAutosize matAutosizeMinRows=10 matAutosizeMaxRows=10>
```

Comment: You're basically asking how to build a rich-text edit box, or a WYSIWYG editor.  I'd use an off-the-shelf text editor like ngx-editor instead: https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-editor.

Comment: you can go with ckeditor